# Zookeeper : assign range to clients

Tags: apache-zookeeper, spring-cloud-zookeeper, php-zookeeper

How can I get zookeeper to manage range of number say 1 to 50, 51 to 100 etc to clients C1, C2,C3 as and when more clients connect into the group and get a range assigned?